# Is it possible to get seconds remaining of scheduled celery task

Tags: django, celery

Is it possible to get seconds remaining to start scheduled celery task
. eg: my_task.apply_async(countdown=100)

Answer (score 0):

You could see the dump of scheduled tasks http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#dump-of-scheduled-eta-tasks

Every task has `eta` param, so you can calculate remaining time.

Comment: Thanks for reply, currently I'm calculating from eta.